# Espresso + Cucumber - is it possible to handle few steps with one test

Tags: android, cucumber, gherkin

I am unable to write more than one annotation above my test.

For scenario:

```
Feature: Login Tests
  @example
  Scenario: Login
    Given I am on the Login Screen
    When  I login with "haha@hihi.com" and "qq123456
```

I have two working tests:

```
    @Test
    @Given("^I am on the Login Screen$")
    public void i_am_on_the_Login_Screen() throws InterruptedException {
        mLoginPage.waitForPageVisible();
    }

    @Test
    @When("^I login with \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_login_with_and(String user, String password) throws InterruptedException {
        mLoginPage.typeUser(user);
        Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard();
        mLoginPage.typePassword(password);
        Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard();
        mLoginPage.tapLoginBtn();
    }
```

And what I would like to do is to merge it like that:

```
@Test
@Given("^I am on the Login Screen$")
@When("^I login with \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void i_login_with_and1(String user, String password) throws InterruptedException {
    mLoginPage.waitForPageVisible();

    mLoginPage.typeUser(user);
    Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard();
    mLoginPage.typePassword(password);
    Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard();
    mLoginPage.tapLoginBtn();
}
```

But I am unable to place few annotations above single test. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a step to be on the login screen. Just add that to the login step and remove the navigating step entirely.

Comment: This only an example. My testing framework is quite big and I am thinking about including BDD. I want to see/test limits of cucumber. Thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you use cucumber you don't need `@Test` annotation
2. It is possible to put many annotations on a method

Like in your example :

```
    @Given("^I am on the Login Screen$")
    @When("^I login with \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_login_with_and1(String user, String password) throws InterruptedException {
....
```

3. If you keep you gherkin scenario the same the method `i_login_with_and1` will be called 2 times.

So, yes you can. But it is better not to(and I don't see any reason why you need that). Also if you do not change the gherkin the tests will probably fail.